# Formula about relaxed ménage problem

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I was reading about [relaxed ménage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9nage_problem) on [this page](https://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Edoyle/docs/menage/menage/node2.html):

> The relaxed ménage problem asks for the number  of $m_n$ ways of seating  couples around a circular table, so that no one sits next to his or her partner. This is nearly the same as the ménage problem, only now we have relaxed the requirement that men and women alternate.
>
> To determine $m_n$ , we begin with the set $S$ of all $\left(2n\right)!$ ways of seating the  individuals around the table, and use inclusion-exclusion on the set of couples who end up sitting together. Let us call the elements of $S$  seatings, and let us denote by $w_k$ the number of seatings under which some specified set of $k$ couples (and possibly some other couples) end up sitting together. Clearly $w_k$,  does not depend on the particular set of $k$ couples we choose, and so, by the principle of inclusion and exclusion, we have:

$$m_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(-1\right)^{k}\binom{n}{k}w_{k}$$

---

I don't know how the principle of inclusion and exclusion has been used here,so can someone please derive the formula and explain where does it come from?

Comment: The formula is just a rewriting of inclusion-exclusion principle, since there are $\binom nk $ ways to choose k couples out of $n $ and $w_k $ obviously does not depend on a particular  choice.

Comment: Well the "rewriting of inclusion-exclusion principle" is what I don't get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general information about inclusion-exclusion principle can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). Below I will reproduce the most essential points important for understanding the particular problem.

In general the inclusion-exclusion principle states that for finite sets $A_1,\dots, A_n$, one has the identity:
$$\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right| = \sum_{i=1}^n |A_i| - \sum_{1 \leqslant i < j \leqslant n} |A_i\cap A_j| + \sum_{1 \leqslant i < j < k \leqslant n} |A_i \cap A_j\cap A_k| - \cdots + (-1)^{n-1} \left|A_1\cap\cdots\cap A_n\right|.$$

In the applications it is common to see the principle expressed in its complementary form. That is, letting $S$ be a finite universal set containing all of the $A_i$ and letting $\bar A_{i}$ denote the complement of $A_i$ in $S$:

$$\left|\bigcap_{i=1}^n \bar{A_i}\right| = \left|S\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \right| =|S| - \sum_{i=1}^n |A_i| + \sum_{1 \leqslant i < j \leqslant n} |A_i\cap A_j| - \cdots + (-1)^n |A_1\cap\cdots\cap A_n|.\tag1$$

If the size, $w_k$, of the intersection sets  appearing in the formula (1) depends only on the number of sets, $k$, in the intersections (i.e. $\forall i:\, |A_i|=w_1,\; \forall i<j:\, |A_i\cap A_j|\equiv w_2$, and so on), the expression can be simplified to:
$$
\left|\bigcap_{i=1}^n \bar{A_i}\right|  =\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{k}\binom nk w_k.
$$

This is exactly the case in the considered problem, with $A_i$ being the set of all permutations with $i$-th couple sitting together.

Comment: Why can't we choose $k$ couples of $n$ wo end up sitting together and then permute the other couples? In my opinion we should subtract the permutations where at least $1$ couple end up sitting together from the whole permutations which is $\left(2n\right)!$,and denote $A_{i_1}$ to be the set of all permutations such that one couple end up sitting together,and denote $A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2}$ to be the set of all permutations such that tow couples end up sitting together,and so on.This kind of computation is like what we do to determine the number of derangements on a set $[n]$.

Comment: Here one performs essentially the same procedure. In the derangement problem $w_k= (n-k)!$, in the considered problem it will be different.

Comment: Why cannot we say : choose $k$ couples out if $n$ end up sitting together and then permute the others in $w_k=\left(2n-2k\right)!$ ways?

Comment: The computation of the particular $w_k$ is already next question. Short answer: for the considered problem it is incorrect. This however has nothing to do with the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but can you tell me why is not that correct?

Comment: In the derangement problem the "correct" positions for the numbers are already given. In the considered problem you have a freedom to choose them. The freedom is however restricted by the requirement that the couples cannot "overlap". Additional problem is the circular arrangement. Taking all this into account one ends up with much more complicated expression than $(2n-2k)!$, but this factor will be of course also present.

Comment: @ user,what you say is true,but why we don't say : $$m_{n}=\left(2n\right)!-\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}{A_i}\right|=\left(2n\right)!+\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{k}w_k$$ Which means subtract the unwanted cases from the all cases.

Comment: I don't quite understand you. This *is* exactly what we say. Your final expression and $$\sum_{k=\color{red}0}^n(-1)^k\binom nk w_k$$ are identical.

Comment: So I think $w_0$ is equal to $\left|S\right|$ (if yes then why? I mean $w_0$ in the number of ways that $0$ couples end up sitting together,however $S$ is the number of ways that $2n$ individuals can sit around a circular table,I don't know how they are equal),and thanks for your patience and comments.

Comment: Let us read your original text a bit more careful. "... let us denote by $w_k$ the number of seatings under which some specified set of $k$ couples (**and possibly some other couples**) end up sitting together". In other words $w_k$ is the number of seatings where **at least** $k$ couples sit together. Therefore $w_0$ is the number of **unrestricted** seatings, i.e. $(2n)!$.

Comment: Wow,nice,so $w_0$ in the number of ways for which **at least** $0$ couples end up sitting together,which is exactly $(2n!)$